# Antd Dropdown component with OK and reset options

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to use `Dropdown` component and provide two options `OK` and `reset` buttons (as provided in [Table](https://ant.design/components/table/) example),

after some research I didn't find any mention about this functionality in [Dropdown](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) or [Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/) component api,

Does anyone implemented such functionality outside of `Table` components, any inputs how this is work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5733) issue in github such functionality can be reached via `Popover` with `Menu` + `Buttons`

Answer (score 1):

The code implementing the `OK` and `RESET` options of that component are implemented specifically for the `table` dropdown here (https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/filterDropdown.tsx#L196-L222).

You can either implement it similarly (i.e. wrap the `Menu` with a div and handle the events yourself) or you could create an ant design github ticket and ask whether a) this should be part of the design specification  and b) whether there should be a reusuable way to consume this

Comment: big thanks for this code, and yes, opened the issue in github to provide this api: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5733

Answer (score -5):

You will want to bind to the change event via javascript/jQuery.

On `$(document.ready()` you can call a function that will do this binding.

Then you just check the value of the dropdown via a jQuery selector.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("dropdownSelector").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).value();
        //logic to do things
    });
});
</script>
```

You can check out different ways to use jQuery selectors here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: How does jQuery relate here? Please read the question before answer

Comment: This API looks like an HTML extension, am I wrong? Any HTML object has its own events, so you can use Jqeury to bind to events the API doesn't natively support.

If your API doesn't have a Changed event, then you can just hook into the <input> object's change event through what I posted there.